# How to translate my php core login to codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to do a login with condeigniter because i'm new using it,but however I dont how to translate my php core login into this framework I could traslate my model and ajax with codeignite, but I couldnt all the controller into the codeingiter. how can I do it?

Login controller

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    public function login(){
        $data['module'] = "Index";
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function login($username,$password){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT iduser,name,last_name,username,password,typeuser_idtypeuser from user INNER JOIN typeuser ON user.typeuser_idtypeuser = typeuser.idtypeuser WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

ajax login

```
$(function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    URL_GET_ACCESS = BASE_URL +"login_controller/index";
    $.ajax({
        url : BASE_URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password;

    }).done(function(resp){
        if(resp === '0'){
            $('#error').show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
        }else if(resp === '1'){
            //web
        }else{
            //other web
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

php core controller

```
   switch ($boton) {
    case 'logout':
        session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['session_user_id'])){
            $user = new user();
            $user->updateCheckPoint($_SESSION['session_user_id']);
        }
        session_destroy();
        break;
    case 'login':
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $ins = new user();

        $array = $ins->identification($username, $password);
        if ($array[0] == 0) {
            echo 0;
        } else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'YES'; 
            $_SESSION['full_name'] = $array[1] . ' ' . $array[2];
            $_SESSION['session_type_user'] = $array[5];
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by your php core? A native php code you have written?

Comment: yea. a native php code

Comment: I see that you have started your codeigniter code, but yet you need to be more specific with what problem you have encounter that suitable to [ask] in stackoverflow guidelines

Comment: i did not get your problem in this question please elaborate more and point to point question so we have better understanding what  you want to ask